# Show there exists another polynomial with specified roots.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $\alpha$ be a complex number.

Suppose there exists a a monic polynomial $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $f(\alpha)=0$. Show that there exists a monic polynomial $g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $g(\alpha ^2)=0$.

I tried to compute the elementary symmetric polynomials in order to put them in the coefficients, but it became increasingly non-practical, and I had no way to guarantee that the numbers are integers.

Comment: You probably want to exclude $f=0$; and $g=0$.

Comment: Included more information, thank you.

Comment: But "monic" is much stronger than "nonzero".

Comment: The result can be computed as resultant, $g(y)=Res_x(f(x),y-x^2)$. If the properties of the resultant are known, the claims follow directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: What's the relationship between the coefficients of $\prod_{i=1}^n (x-r_i)$ and $\prod_{i=1}^n (x+r_i)$?

Comment: This root-squaring procedure is the basis of the Dandelin-Gräffe method. -- More generally, if $q=\exp(i\,2\pi/d)$, then $f(x)f(qx)...f(q^{d-1}x)$ is a polynomial $g(x^d)$ that only contains powers of $x^d$.